# How to obtain Couchbase Server version using the Couchbase Python SDK?

Tags: python, version, couchbase

I'm trying to get Couchbase Server version using the Couchbase Python SDK.

I can do this using couchbase-cli but I need to get this information using Python.

I tried to use following code but returned AttributeError: 'Cluster' object has no attribute 'raw_result'

```
from couchbase.result import ClusterInfoResult as cir 

version = cir(cluster).server_version_full
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Couchbase server version by calling the `cluster_info()` on the cluster object in SDK v4.1.

`cluster.cluster_info().server_version_full`

Reference: https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-python-client/couchbase_api/couchbase_core.html#couchbase.cluster.Cluster.cluster_info